# transformation patterns don't work with constants

Tags: pattern-matching

I want to do the reverse of PowerExpand and convert 2*Log[x+y] to Log[(x+y)^2].
The rule:

```
 t_ Log[x_] -> Log[x^t]
```

works for `a Log[y], a Log[Pi], Pi Log[a], 2 Log[a], a Log[2]`
but not for `2 Log[Pi], Pi Log[2], Pi Log[EulerGamma]`.

Entering:

```
Pi Log[Pi] /. Pi Log[Pi] -> Log[Pi^Pi]
```

Returns:

```
Pi Log[Pi]
```

instead of:

```
Log[Pi^Pi]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's doing it and then simplifying back.
Try :

```
Pi Log[Pi] /. {x_ Log[y_] -> Hold[Log[y^x]]}
```

Comment: If only appearance is important you could also use `HoldForm`.